# Why is an std::vector of noncopyable elements copyable (according to concepts)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

```
#include<concepts>
#include<vector>

struct nc { nc(const nc&) = delete; };
static_assert(!std::copyable<nc>);  // OK
static_assert(!std::copyable<std::vector<nc>>);  // fails, why?
```

I have tried this with both gcc 13 and clang 17. Is this a bug in those compilers (or the respective library implementations) or is it really the desired behaviour? Obviously, `std::vector<nc>` is not copyable as the following fails to compile:

```
std::vector<nc> v;
std::vector<nc> w = v;  // does not compile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out this article: [Why does `std::is_copy_constructible` report that a vector of move-only objects is copy constructible?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190926-00/?p=102924)

The TLDR is `is_copy_constructible` only checks that there is a copy constructor, not that it is a valid copy constructor. `std::vector` *does* have a copy constructor, but it is not a valid one if you try to compile it for this type. But `is_copy_constructible` doesn't try that, because the constructor could be defined elsewhere, and the type-trait cannot go and verify whether or not it is a valid definition.

Comment: I think the better way to say it, is that the type trait only checks if the copy constructor is declared. It doesn't check if it compiles. It is library's responsibility that there is no discongruity between the two.

Comment: This is a defect and should be reported. If the copy constructor and assignment operator of `std::vector` are properly constraint, the assertion must succeed. So, either the `std::vector` is defect or the compiler core  or both

Comment: Language lawyers must reply.

Comment: I think I get it. The copy constructor of vector is not constrained, and if I understand it correctly, changing this would be ABI-breakage; so, in other words, not happening soon…

Comment: The reason why `std::vector<T>` doesn't delete its own copy constructor when `T` is noncopyable is that `T` is allowed to be an incomplete type, which means that the signatures of all of `std::vector<T>`'s member functions cannot depend on whether or not `T` has some property that will only be known after `T` is complete.